# Javascript JSONP callback function is method of object?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

```
function handler1(data) { }
function objectA {
  this.handler2 = function(data) { }
}
```

I can call JSONP page and receive data with handler1 function. But I need to use OOP. How can I call JSONP page and receive data with objectA.handler2 function?

Answer (score 0):

in the same way, - `objectA_instance.handler2( data )`. Nothing fancy.